# MySqli - how can i SELECT ALL WHERE AND WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get data from a table like the following:

```
SELECT Category,Icon_class,uri FROM 
`menu_links` 
JOIN 
users 
ON users.role_id = 1 WHERE Category ='employees' AND  'scoreboard'
```

I want to get certain rows only, and not the whole table. Mysql returns a syntax error.

Thanks!

Comment: complete on clause like `.menu_links.somematchingfield`

Comment: In which column you need to check the value `scoreboard`

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Nice meta post.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
WHERE Category IN ('employees', 'scoreboard')
```

This assumes that you want records having a category of either employee or scoreboard.  If you want something else, then let us know.

Comment: I have a feeling he wants those that answer both criteria, but lets wait for the OP to comment.

Comment: Yes, i wish to have both, i'm not sure if this is the right way to fetch data, so i'm open for ideas

Comment: A record can (presumably) have only one category.  If you want a certain _group_ of records having both categories this is also possible.  In any case you should post sample data along with desired output.

Answer (score 2):

try with OR Category ='scoreboard'

```
SELECT Category,Icon_class,uri FROM `menu_links` JOIN users ON users.role_id = 1 WHERE Category ='employees' OR Category ='scoreboard'
```